# Class-variables access in super method of Python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, super

Assume, I have similar code:

```
class Parent:
  CONST_VAL = '1'
  
  def calc(self):
     return self.CONST_VAL

class Child(Parent):
  CONST_VAL = 'child'

  def calc(self):
     return super().calc() + self.CONST_VAL
```

And then I execute the following:

```
c = Child()
c.calc()

>> childchild
```

I expect it to be '1child', but it's not.

Is there a right way to make a class-variable isolation of super methods like in C++?

Comment: You are calling parent instance variable and overrites it in your child class.
In Your parent class return Parent.CONST_VAL ,so that when python interpreter runs it knows from where to pick the value of CONST_VAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both of your methods you use `self.CONST_VAL` - this is an **instance** variable.

When you call `super().calc()` you indeed call method `calc()` of `Parent` class, but it also returns **instance** variable, which is the same, obviously.

What you might want to do is to use `Parent.CONST_VAL` in you parent class.